# PostgreSQL: Compare Two Arrays Is Any One Value Exists In Second Array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, group-by, any

I am trying to join two tables and each table having one array column. And my intension is to compare two arrays if any value of the first array exists in the second array.

I am writing where clause like below

```
any(table1.array1) = any(table2.array2)
```

But it is not working for me.

Comment: Without seeing your table structures and sample data it is very hard to answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator && should do the trick. This will return if any of elements in Array1 is present in Array2.
Refer to PostgreSQL document here:  [Array Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

```
select array[1,2,3] && array[2,4,5], array[1,2,3] && array[4,5, 6], array[1,2,3] && array[1]
Output: true, false, true
```

If you are looking if all the elements present in second array, you should use @> or <@